# Can't execute iMacros macros

Tags: macros, imacros

I use iMacros (Google Chrome). Everything was fine for more than a year but suddenly today i can't execute my macros (.iim files). I make a double-click or hit the button <kbd>Play Macro</kbd> and it doesnt do anything. I can't edit them too and also i can't record a new macro (when i hit Stop, then there is only white window with no info and i cant save it or anything else). But i can rename macros and remove. Why i cant execute my macros? Where could be the problem? I havent changed anything and few days ago everything was working as it is supposed to be.

Comment: ok, here is the answer... http://imacros.net/chrome-35-update-breaks-imacros-chrome now switching to FF. sorry for the pointless question.